# two submit in one form with diffrent actions based on post

Tags: php, forms, post

this is the form:

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
      <input type="text" class="field small-field" name="refone" value="<?php echo Check_Param($refone);?>" />
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="search" name="search"/>
      <input type="submit" class="button" name="print" value="print" />
    </form>
```

Now here I have two action,

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['search']))  {
```

if the search button click this action only will run

```
} else{
```

in not submitting the form this action will be run.

```
}
```

Now this is action for print which will use the if statement and then result it on this if

```
if(isset($_POST['print'])){
```

here when i click the print the upper function runs from the **else** of first **if** and then it's printing the result here which will export it to PDF as on search button it was only searching and resulting but in print it will print it,

```
}
```

so my question is how I can set the **print** to first go to **first if** which will search then come to **if(print)** and results.

as here I did so but it's not working here::

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['search']) || isset($_POST['print']))  {
/////////////this code runs first
```

}

```
if(isset($_POST['print'])){
/////////this runs secound based on resulted rows of first if
}
```

so how I can manage it

regards

Comment: what does the search results contain anyway? maybe you need to persist whatever results it may return, and then when print is pressed, use the search results

Comment: actully i want here when i click print it run both if statment

Comment: sorry man, still cant understand

Comment: its like first if runs then there will be post a result and exits
then the next if runs based on first result.

Comment: thats what i'm saying, your results from the first if must persist (can be sessions), so that when the print button is submitted, the result from the first if can be reused

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap them with `()` so they'll evaluate separately.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && (isset($_POST['search']) || isset($_POST['print'])))  {

    if(isset($_POST['print'])){

       //this runs secound based on resulted rows of first if

    }

}
```